# How can I vectorize fictional single word (not sentence!) for classification?

Tags: natural-language-processing, reference-request, classification, feature-engineering, vectors

I am working on fictional single words (names) generator that have to sound like words from a given sample. I have the generator up and running that gives reasonable words 70% of time. I thought of improving this value, ideally to ~99% (so no manual step is necessary to discard clearly missed words).

I've already attempted *fuzzy matching* to any word in the initial sample (and rejecting words below given thresholds), and this winded up reasonable answers to 95%-99%, but in my experiments this approach is rejecting too many well-sounding names (even 60-70 rejections per 1 generated name - this removes a lot of entropy from the initial set).

Now, I am thinking of using classification instead to tackle the problem from another angle: using classification to discard the generated name.

The problem I have is I have to vectorize a single word based on its sound for classification. I've already excessively searched the Internet and the only solution I see are for vectorizing *texts*, not *single words*.

So, the question here: what kind of algorithm for vectorization of single fictional word based on its sounding have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more excessive search I have found the description of [Phonetic Matching](https://stevemorse.org/phonetics/bmpm2.htm) algorithm by Alexander Beider and Stephen Morse which basically does what I need to do on filtering